# jQuery letterSpacing animation bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-ui-accordion, letter-spacing

I'm really a beginner to jQuery and today i tried to create this cute sort of horizontal accordion menu, with some text on it.

Now i got the accordion working, but I also tried to animate the letter spacing for the text.

***edit:***
Please note that the width animation is working, the problem is that the letter spacing is not animated **back** to -14px, but jumps back.

I have searched everywhere and cant find the solution.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("ul li a, p").hover(function() { 

    $el = $(this);

    $el.animate({width: "200px", letterSpacing: "0px"
}, { queue:false });
}, function() { 

    $el = $(this);

    $el.animate({width: "120px", letterSpacing: "-14px"
},{ queue:false });
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d5MYS/ - Live code

Thanks :)

Comment: fixing the jquery reference it works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/d5MYS/2/

Comment: If comment above doesnt't solve your problem: fiddle above provides letterspacing animation. What's your question then?

Comment: @Simon
It does work when increasing the spacing but for some reason on the way back it jumps instead of animating...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which web-browser. I can't reproduce this problem with FireFox 12 and I assume you ran into JQuery/Internet Explorer bug described here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8627

Comment: I'm actually using google chrome (on mac if it matters) and I did test it with firefox.
Please note that the width animation does work, but when on the way back to -14px spacing it jumps instead of animating...
Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using ? Did you try to update ?

Comment: I'm using the latest version (1.7.2)